# Cannot access admin URL in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin

My domain is `demo_data.local:8085` and my admin is `admin_geus3n` (got in `app/etc/env.php`). When I go to `demo_data.local:8085/admin_geus3n` I received this error:

```
This page isn’t working
demo_data.local redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

and URL that shown on browser is

```
http://demo_data.local:8085/index.php/admin_geus3n/http:/index/demo_data.local:8085/index.php/admin_geus3n/admin/index/index/key/key/8a837d053fd13572cb93a9d361f4efd0382cbe4fd626d08ce3375cb74ab7c91b/
```

How can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You set this admin_geus3n ? Is this admin name?

Comment: @muasif80 yeah, I get this name in frontName in env.php file

Answer (score 0):

Try 
http://demo_data.local:8085/index.php/admin_geus3n
or 
rename .htaccess in your root folder

Comment: Nothing changed, bro. I had '.htaccess' and '.htaccess.sample' in my root folder

Comment: You have your frontend loading successfully or it is also giving some error? Clear all the logs, then refresh the admin page you might get some error in the log

Comment: If you get 400 code error in admin, set web/seo/use_rewrites to 1 in db.

Comment: I didn't get any log, I think my admin page loading unsuccessfully

Comment: 400 code means bad request, but error I got is too many redirects

Comment: your frontend is loading without any problem?

Comment: yeah, for example, when I go to 'demo_data.local:8085', it loads successfully

Comment: Then your admin url should be like http://demo_data.local:8085/admin_geus3n. Did you try this as well?

Comment: Bro, you have said


Nothing changed, bro. I had '.htaccess' and '.htaccess.sample' in my root folder

Does this mean you have both .htaccess & .htaccess.sample in your root folder?

Comment: Try
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89125/how-to-fix-magento-2-2-0-0-rc-admin-page-not-found-after-installation/89157#89157

Comment: yeah, I saw both two files in my root folder

Comment: Just rename .htaccess to something else. So your root folder must not have .htaccess

Comment: I don't know the reason, but when I remove _ from domain, it works :D. Btw, thanks for your comments

Comment: Good that you have found out!! Super Bro!!